# How to Read KML data in C#?

Tags: c#

How to read KML data and get exact coordinates for Related Country.

Example :
I have a KML data for world country. How to get exact coordinates or placemark for USA country.

I tried below codes, Once i read the KML file that time i can see lots of tables. So, based on the particular table i copied to another datatable.

```
DataSet _ds = new DataSet("MyDataSet");            
_ds.ReadXml(@"E:\World Country.kml");

DataTable dtPlaceMark = new DataTable();
DataTable dtPointer = new DataTable();
dtPlaceMark = _ds.Tables[10].Copy();//Can get PlaceMark_ID
dtPointer = _ds.Tables[14].Copy();//But Can't find out the PlaceMark_ID for in this table.
dtPlaceMark.Merge(dtPointer);//Finally, I Need to merge and get coordinates.
```

Comment: what does your data look like? what columns do dtPlaceMark and dtPointer have?

Comment: The KML is XML data.  There are lots of ways of parsing an XML file.  Can you post the XML so we can provide a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

dtPlaceMark have folloing columns :
Name & PlaceMark_ID
USA       0
IND       1
SG        3
dtPointer have Folling Columns
Coordinates & Coordinates_ID

Below is my XML/KML data:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://earth.google.com/kml/2.0">
<Document>
<name>US-States.shp</name>
<Style id="Mapit">
<IconStyle>
<color>FFFFFFFF</color>
<scale>1.0</scale>
<Icon>
<x>192</x>
<y>192</y>
<w>32</w>
<h>32</h>  </Icon>
</IconStyle>
<LabelStyle>
<scale>0</scale>
</LabelStyle>
<BalloonStyle >
<text>$[description]</text>
<color>FFFFFFFF</color>
</BalloonStyle>
</Style>
<Style id="shp2kml">
<IconStyle>
<color>FFFFCA95</color>
<scale>1.0</scale>
</IconStyle>
<LabelStyle>
<scale>0</scale>
</LabelStyle>
<BalloonStyle >
<text>$[description]</text>
<color>FFFFFFFF</color>
</BalloonStyle>
<LineStyle>
<color>FFFF0000</color>
<width>1</width>
</LineStyle>
<PolyStyle>
<color>FFFFCA95</color>
</PolyStyle>
</Style>
<Folder>
<name>Features</name>
<Snippet>Legend: Single Symbol</Snippet>
<open>0</open>
<visibility>1</visibility>
<Placemark>
<name>AL</name>
<Snippet></Snippet>
<description>
<![CDATA[<table border=0 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0  width=250 style="FONT-SIZE: 11px; FONT-FAMILY: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">
<tr>
<td bgcolor="#E3E1CA" align="right">
<font COLOR="#000000">
<b>CODE</b>
</font>
</td>
<td bgcolor="#E4E6CA"> <font COLOR="#008000">AL</font>
</td>
</tr>
</table>]]>
</description>
<styleUrl>#shp2kml</styleUrl>
<Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>-84.92368,32.247389,0.0 -84.916004,32.228556,0.0 -84.928372,32.217978,0.0 -84.975744,32.212249,0.0 -84.960385,32.191928,0.0 -85.007826,32.178879,0.0 -85.024382,32.166275,0.0 -85.053314,32.126638,0.0 -85.046187,32.090895,0.0 -85.056655,32.069644,0.0 -85.062011,32.05001,0.0 -85.0567,32.017377,0.0 -85.070067,31.980703,0.0</coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon>
</Placemark>
<Placemark>
<name>AK</name>
<Snippet></Snippet>
<description>
<![CDATA[<table border=0 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0  width=250 style="FONT-SIZE: 11px; FONT-FAMILY: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">
<tr>
<td bgcolor="#E3E1CA" align="right">
<font COLOR="#000000">
<b>CODE</b>
</font>
</td>
<td bgcolor="#E4E6CA"> <font COLOR="#008000">AK</font>
</td>
</tr>
</table>]]>
</description>
<styleUrl>#shp2kml</styleUrl>
<MultiGeometry><Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>-161.333785,58.733248,0.0 -159.431907,58.782004,0.0 -159.652767,58.835614,0.0 -159.629389,58.951729,0.0 -159.770814,58.933668,0.0 -159.764983,58.853397,0.0 -159.921353,58.770334,0.0 -160.018039,58.884783,0.0 -160.251929,58.894775,0.0 -160.322214,58.949776,0.0 -160.255289,58.981439,0.0 -160.328871,59.058947,0.0 -160.835706,58.836057,0.0 -160.89888,58.884774,0.0 -161.29973,58.809208,0.0 -161.265686,58.774635,0.0 -161.333785,58.733248,0.0</coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon><Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>-172.282643,60.30176,0.0 -172.601782,60.323974,0.0 -173.05103,60.493397,0.0 -173.046851,60.537015,0.0 -172.919347,60.602854,0.0 -172.847102,60.483965,0.0 -172.390441,60.392868,0.0 -172.211808,60.316205,0.0 -172.282643,60.30176,0.0</coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon><Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>-166.11144,60.40947,0.0 -166.066484,60.327531,0.0 -165.683704,60.293921,0.0 -165.73283,60.16503,0.0 -165.675057,60.096687,0.0 -165.72785,60.065581,0.0 -165.542848,59.978632,0.0 -165.614469,59.901412,0.0 -166.267815,59.843079,0.0 -166.11892,59.810572,0.0 -166.104757,59.757242,0.0 -167.128929,59.996396,0.0 -167.318112,60.070849,0.0 -167.453134,60.206679,0.0 -166.841435,60.203904,0.0 -166.810311,60.279458,0.0 -166.498123,60.378071,0.0 -166.398666,60.340024,0.0 -166.11144,60.40947,0.0</coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon><Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>-164.178091,54.603271,0.0 -164.388378,54.441869,0.0 -164.647263,54.389931,0.0 -164.855308,54.424366,0.0 -164.953642,54.58631,0.0 -164.706139,54.667432,0.0 -164.490015,54.915507,0.0 -164.221437,54.886623,0.0 -164.137823,54.964953,0.0 -163.770614,55.055224,0.0 -163.531996,55.045515,0.0 -163.361973,54.775496,0.0 -163.147019,54.765216,0.0 -163.050603,54.667443,0.0 -163.370853,54.753554,0.0 -163.438385,54.657438,0.0 -163.601959,54.609935,0.0 -164.178091,54.603271,0.0</coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon><Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>-166.645219,53.522742,0.0 -166.711319,53.546355,0.0 -166.667708,53.481076,0.0 -166.79106,53.562742,0.0 -166.754709,53.445521,0.0 -166.88746,53.476623,0.0 -167.143566,53.415782,0.0 -167.500759,53.255752,0.0 -167.666948,53.236582,0.0 -167.844705,53.303252,0.0 -167.693324,53.38383,0.0 -167.485228,53.371603,0.0 -167.478547,53.434667,0.0 -167.326072,53.404658,0.0 -167.304952,53.469386,0.0 -167.162732,53.465231,0.0 -167.184097,53.518839,0.0 -166.964121,53.525229,0.0 -167.161883,53.592458,0.0 -166.997964,53.614679,0.0 -167.065537,53.664965,0.0 -167.031906,53.701078,0.0 -166.90245,53.707192,0.0 -166.803268,53.624688,0.0 -166.827439,53.699686,0.0 -166.708269,53.716631,0.0 -167.031909,53.750801,0.0 -167.162751,53.852751,0.0 -166.752505,54.0083,0.0 -166.592989,53.965233,0.0 -166.639401,53.91801,0.0 -166.601617,53.827471,0.0 -166.458043,53.8844,0.0 -166.375514,54.001343,0.0 -166.37079,53.94412,0.0 -166.26641,53.973287,0.0 -166.266408,53.908015,0.0 -166.216945,53.927462,0.0 -166.539118,53.781906,0.0 -166.490201,53.771631,0.0 -166.572714,53.709422,0.0 -166.485803,53.688863,0.0 -166.417176,53.755536,0.0 -166.373841,53.714423,0.0 -166.333594,53.778019,0.0 -166.279117,53.67775,0.0 -166.540214,53.626911,0.0 -166.5927,53.534417,0.0 -166.665821,53.592468,0.0 -166.645219,53.522742,0.0</coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon><Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>-166.221354,53.703867,0.0 -166.295237,53.792202,0.0 -166.091951,53.838582,0.0 -166.221354,53.703867,0.0</coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon><Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>-167.797253,53.494654,0.0 -167.850843,53.37992,0.0 -168.287532,53.235187,0.0 -168.472312,53.045981,0.0 -169.109577,52.818123,0.0 -168.882379,52.937324,0.0 -168.770404,53.066802,0.0 -168.795959,53.146526,0.0 -168.623432,53.271294,0.0 -168.360903,53.2588,0.0 -168.430645,53.33214,0.0 -168.353939,53.474649,0.0 -168.007523,53.562712,0.0 -167.797253,53.494654,0.0</coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon><Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>-174.16133,52.417347,0.0 -173.991826,52.320126,0.0 -174.065457,52.222336,0.0 -174.196532,52.221776,0.0 -174.100971,52.102619,0.0 -174.434362,52.105941,0.0 -174.377078,52.096765,0.0 -174.416045,52.036213,0.0 -174.523536,52.089266,0.0 -174.487642,52.033708,0.0 -174.704054,52.049532,0.0 -174.722148,52.000921,0.0 -175.33827,52.012841,0.0 -175.024351,52.020635,0.0 -174.906889,52.110373,0.0 -174.579631,52.099542,0.0 -174.499368,52.139273,0.0 -174.551313,52.175665,0.0 -174.23462,52.241788,0.0 -174.448533,52.311776,0.0 -174.16133,52.417347,0.0</coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon><Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>-176.941084,51.583033,0.0 -176.974723,51.65636,0.0 -176.818022,51.768592,0.0 -176.90775,51.804982,0.0 -176.704951,51.781949,0.0 -176.78165,51.823328,0.0 -176.703036,51.851394,0.0 -176.774177,51.943884,0.0 -176.558365,51.982222,0.0 -176.548588,51.908607,0.0 -176.644715,51.855837,0.0 -176.428853,51.835004,0.0 -176.432198,51.728892,0.0 -176.509137,51.751945,0.0 -176.800545,51.602762,0.0 -176.82888,51.712757,0.0 -176.941084,51.583033,0.0</coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon><Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>-177.910315,51.590475,0.0 -178.103365,51.663259,0.0 -177.957791,51.763271,0.0 -178.217598,51.87522,0.0 -177.948677,51.917729,0.0 -177.836721,51.830776,0.0 -177.621988,51.850798,0.0 -177.799758,51.787448,0.0 -177.910315,51.590475,0.0</coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon><Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>-171.086946,63.431856,0.0 -171.451643,63.31351,0.0 -171.73392,63.369602,0.0 -171.853627,63.50767,0.0 -171.743068,63.666567,0.0 -171.739231,63.788792,0.0 -171.681459,63.792128,0.0 -171.637259,63.693502,0.0 -171.405584,63.642124,0.0 -171.5117,63.644074,0.0 -171.547252,63.613791,0.0 -171.491401,63.595734,0.0 -171.328095,63.632964,0.0 -170.917238,63.570475,0.0 -170.654414,63.676877,0.0 -170.302739,63.693268,0.0 -170.0688,63.594663,0.0 -170.034399,63.535772,0.0 -170.086003,63.484943,0.0 -169.179314,63.298022,0.0 -168.692896,63.302192,0.0 -168.852591,63.154412,0.0 -169.327934,63.182179,0.0 -169.656273,62.943274,0.0 -169.80794,63.124379,0.0 -169.980209,63.141987,0.0 -170.239896,63.281603,0.0 -170.859426,63.461031,0.0 -171.086946,63.431856,0.0</coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon><Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>-146.098975,60.392222,0.0 -146.604255,60.237498,0.0 -146.679533,60.287216,0.0 -146.488147,60.366939,0.0 -146.726197,60.37415,0.0 -146.582872,60.481944,0.0 -146.098975,60.392222,0.0</coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon><Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>-146.939833,60.285823,0.0 -147.240863,60.128543,0.0 -147.367592,60.026034,0.0 -147.354015,59.974651,0.0 -147.482391,59.945765,0.0 -147.471865,59.867994,0.0 -147.91232,59.790178,0.0 -147.7431,59.893247,0.0 -147.802841,59.920729,0.0 -147.669519,59.969642,0.0 -147.698932,59.998238,0.0 -147.194998,60.244936,0.0 -147.195545,60.352713,0.0 -147.010989,60.341933,0.0 -147.100357,60.27026,0.0 -146.939833,60.285823,0.0</coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon><Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>-152.093219,58.359562,0.0 -152.148252,58.231772,0.0 -151.99712,58.346777,0.0 -151.964615,58.280388,0.0 -152.082424,58.155654,0.0 -152.193823,58.173717,0.0 -152.249365,58.266779,0.0 -152.321883,58.240113,0.0 -152.301314,58.186773,0.0 -152.369647,58.196217,0.0 -152.276596,58.127046,0.0 -152.544963,58.084542,0.0 -152.561622,58.207054,0.0 -152.628559,58.077885,0.0 -152.774715,58.071502,0.0 -152.789154,57.991768,0.0 -153.233588,58.168458,0.0 -153.183317,58.215959,0.0 -152.90692,58.164558,0.0 -153.108025,58.263742,0.0 -153.014976,58.302903,0.0 -152.762197,58.257346,0.0 -152.765247,58.360963,0.0 -152.886646,58.406797,0.0 -152.694132,58.421794,0.0 -152.660223,58.476515,0.0 -152.499107,58.462067,0.0 -152.52856,58.412899,0.0 -152.401327,58.315111,0.0 -152.349652,58.420671,0.0 -152.093219,58.359562,0.0</coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon><Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>-133.957575,57.299931,0.0 -134.176451,57.384098,0.0 -134.083949,57.2541,0.0 -134.361999,57.079939,0.0 -134.614236,57.0091,0.0 -134.580637,57.148826,0.0 -134.635938,57.215493,0.0 -134.513711,57.218544,0.0 -134.583417,57.270494,0.0 -134.454233,57.312157,0.0 -134.557603,57.391329,0.0 -134.342839,57.327994,0.0 -134.306462,57.388548,0.0 -134.47035,57.393274,0.0 -134.57427,57.489382,0.0 -134.35786,57.546051,0.0 -134.575094,57.505495,0.0 -134.662594,57.607164,0.0 -134.805405,58.043821,0.0 -134.730118,58.181046,0.0 -134.790697,58.104376,0.0 -134.914301,58.204932,0.0 -134.881769,58.254104,0.0 -134.94708,58.281601,0.0 -134.958465,58.407435,0.0 -134.805685,58.323275,0.0 -134.687604,58.162431,0.0 -134.170914,58.159384,0.0 -134.179549,58.083271,0.0 -133.893703,57.796881,0.0 -133.877551,57.67243,0.0 -133.792284,57.597707,0.0 -133.961997,57.684095,0.0 -134.233687,58.026322,0.0 -134.157877,57.994104,0.0 -134.311482,58.0916,0.0 -134.263443,58.027993,0.0 -134.321765,58.028267,0.0 -134.225353,57.974655,0.0 -134.320085,57.987991,0.0 -134.287579,57.826881,0.0 -134.238688,57.85855,0.0 -134.045345,57.683264,0.0 -134.076168,57.644933,0.0 -133.938403,57.620764,0.0 -133.842001,57.460209,0.0 -134.081447,57.501049,0.0 -134.043696,57.474926,0.0 -134.100064,57.463542,0.0 -133.972833,57.443813,0.0 -133.997004,57.407703,0.0 -133.883659,57.415204,0.0 -133.865044,57.353543,0.0 -133.957575,57.299931,0.0</coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon><Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>-134.517615,58.337717,0.0 -134.261497,58.194662,0.0 -134.609812,58.237438,0.0 -134.68486,58.302716,0.0 -134.517615,58.337717,0.0</coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon><Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>135.88779,57.987682,0.0 -135.361765,57.796874,0.0 -135.317878,57.754654,0.0 -135.358715,57.720198,0.0 --134.917058,57.752988,0.0 -134.813442,57.48104,0.0 -134.990081,57.450206,0.0 -135.80598,57.762974,0.0 -135.704867,57.673812,0.0 -135.805429,57.639362,0.0 -135.572351,57.58825,0.0 -135.658474,57.551032,0.0 -135.557639,57.538536,0.0 -135.548754,57.459084,0.0 -135.689838,57.362416,0.0 -135.841787,57.387968,0.0 -136.012363,57.511571,0.0 -135.781247,57.435464,0.0 -136.067643,57.595456,0.0 -135.953476,57.616023,0.0 -136.120413,57.616839,0.0 -136.090418,57.682398,0.0 -136.229613,57.78379,0.0 -136.416301,57.820454,0.0 -136.409572,57.833473,0.0 -136.328221,57.990721,0.0 -136.033201,57.842927,0.0 -136.033109,57.842889,0.0 -136.032682,57.842672,0.0 -136.033079,57.842931,0.0 -136.434066,58.107385,0.0 -136.272389,58.10434,0.0 -136.35682,58.212399,0.0 -136.277404,58.218516,0.0 -136.195972,58.080454,0.0 -136.103473,58.056843,0.0 -136.182119,58.177411,0.0 -136.110984,58.2188,0.0 -135.967636,58.159638,0.0 -135.796831,58.277148,0.0 -135.48429,58.155208,0.0 -135.605692,58.043539,0.0 -135.782393,58.045755,0.0 -135.624033,58.009374,0.0 -135.794325,57.981581,0.0 -135.649597,57.944644,0.0 -135.400975,58.139096,0.0 -134.943165,58.035488,0.0 -134.907636,57.928823,0.0 -134.971783,57.884931,0.0 -134.919015,57.839376,0.0 -135.2065,57.941874,0.0 -134.932075,57.8066,0.0 -135.012336,57.7766,0.0 -135.236213,57.779649,0.0 -135.889331,57.988243,0.0 -135.88779,57.987682,0.0</coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon><Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>-153.392819,57.157815,0.0 -153.463926,57.110596,0.0 -153.547005,57.170602,0.0 -153.502259,57.063094,0.0 -153.758996,57.045321,0.0 -153.600324,57.047265,0.0 -153.673399,57.008933,0.0 -153.555612,56.977536,0.0 -153.61171,56.93337,0.0 -153.683134,56.968366,0.0 -153.77674,56.889482,0.0 -153.696434,56.86587,0.0 -153.982009,56.737805,0.0 -154.151739,56.745306,0.0 -153.775662,56.989481,0.0 -153.965662,56.988073,0.0 -153.740074,57.130049,0.0 -153.806771,57.15061,0.0 -154.098692,56.962519,0.0 -154.111749,57.043356,0.0 -153.967059,57.115868,0.0 -154.468707,57.126169,0.0 -154.465931,57.064495,0.0 -154.38676,57.044769,0.0 -154.268952,57.116163,0.0 -154.103417,57.115596,0.0 -154.163438,56.956139,0.0 -154.29703,56.906979,0.0 -154.294251,56.86198,0.0 -154.238681,56.881701,0.0 -154.30008,56.848087,0.0 -154.329502,56.926428,0.0 -154.532312,56.989769,0.0 -154.529535,57.147011,0.0 -154.609529,57.259812,0.0 -154.803446,57.28538,0.0 -154.75597,57.300099,0.0 -154.809273,57.338992,0.0 -154.707048,57.334824,0.0 -154.730114,57.421505,0.0 -154.550659,57.54373,0.0 -154.514835,57.514284,0.0 -154.519284,57.577894,0.0 -154.400933,57.563723,0.0 -154.44897,57.579007,0.0 -154.350635,57.64456,0.0 -154.218708,57.667612,0.0 -153.998396,57.634547,0.0 -153.978684,57.56343,0.0 -154.110069,57.53788,0.0 -153.950639,57.541213,0.0 -153.888451,57.404258,0.0 -153.630341,57.268684,0.0 -153.810354,57.399812,0.0 -153.853681,57.566772,0.0 -153.68397,57.543988,0.0 -153.882578,57.642328,0.0 -153.583414,57.611766,0.0 -153.908973,57.707051,0.0 -153.930628,57.810391,0.0 -153.643956,57.889278,0.0 -153.507884,57.625363,0.0 -153.528412,57.715657,0.0 -153.437007,57.699262,0.0 -153.500327,57.767043,0.0 -153.317541,57.725085,0.0 -153.474187,57.841768,0.0 -153.215286,57.787599,0.0 -153.178085,57.70342,0.0 -153.241956,57.895666,0.0 -153.050572,57.830652,0.0 -153.278079,58.00456,0.0 -152.819162,57.916208,0.0 -152.913904,57.8287,0.0 -152.878595,57.726186,0.0 -152.85387,57.83481,0.0 -152.622463,57.855645,0.0 -152.621332,57.927872,0.0 -152.328555,57.813406,0.0 -152.553037,57.697841,0.0 -152.448292,57.721731,0.0 -152.490506,57.647841,0.0 -152.400806,57.685061,0.0 -152.437464,57.603944,0.0 -152.153562,57.603664,0.0 -152.347468,57.423372,0.0 -152.958891,57.520057,0.0 -152.912503,57.483103,0.0 -153.045573,57.430604,0.0 -152.806663,57.467816,0.0 -152.605271,57.379198,0.0 -152.636132,57.316978,0.0 -152.840561,57.26809,0.0 -152.882211,57.346426,0.0 -153.164205,57.347821,0.0 -153.175314,57.299486,0.0 -152.958363,57.253092,0.0 -153.391171,57.206431,0.0 -153.392819,57.157815,0.0</coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon><Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>-134.65539,56.162662,0.0 -135.048431,56.527941,0.0 -134.849536,56.685156,0.0 -134.967306,56.624313,0.0 -134.938987,56.709595,0.0 -134.982325,56.716537,0.0 -135.117028,56.598211,0.0 -135.12426,56.664319,0.0 -134.993986,56.75599,0.0 -135.190088,56.674607,0.0 -135.121759,56.827108,0.0 -135.267053,56.78295,0.0 -135.370635,56.83268,0.0 -135.290095,56.891565,0.0 -135.353147,56.965738,0.0 -135.166222,57.034359,0.0 -135.366754,57.079915,0.0 -135.368705,57.137686,0.0 -135.26595,57.163521,0.0 -135.407892,57.14936,0.0 -135.339528,57.247975,0.0 -135.533996,57.229359,0.0 -135.674302,57.346028,0.0 -135.471228,57.350481,0.0 -135.608994,57.391587,0.0 -135.526764,57.435506,0.0 -135.51598,57.506867,0.0 -135.31456,57.532421,0.0 -135.282363,57.503536,0.0 -135.399577,57.438532,0.0 -135.167614,57.478255,0.0 -135.202064,57.424367,0.0 -135.003993,57.399378,0.0 -134.907613,57.329381,0.0 -135.000908,57.342424,0.0 -134.947866,57.320491,0.0 -134.985067,57.294374,0.0 -134.836198,57.24771,0.0 -134.618144,56.720753,0.0 -134.65539,56.162662,0.0</coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon><Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>-135.702072,57.316583,0.0 -135.557618,57.228802,0.0 -135.626468,57.231305,0.0 -135.547886,57.129075,0.0 -135.63094,57.004082,0.0 -135.839567,56.987685,0.0 -135.825941,57.082967,0.0 -135.710674,57.161018,0.0 -135.819831,57.172401,0.0 -135.848738,57.316295,0.0 -135.702072,57.316583,0.0</coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon><Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>-133.05339,56.977147,0.0 -132.929514,56.859933,0.0 -132.991442,56.806866,0.0 -132.933113,56.629637,0.0 -133.02366,56.601588,0.0 -133.353663,56.838262,0.0 -133.307308,56.731037,0.0 -133.213402,56.708545,0.0 -133.240901,56.631319,0.0 -133.099228,56.615486,0.0 -133.168692,56.601877,0.0 -133.083665,56.523535,0.0 -133.165638,56.453257,0.0 -133.430916,56.501585,0.0 -133.420629,56.454357,0.0 -133.577318,56.433242,0.0 -133.649284,56.443243,0.0 -133.646786,56.563249,0.0 -133.691771,56.568804,0.0 -133.636775,56.593524,0.0 -133.708694,56.677425,0.0 -133.674525,56.858822,0.0 -133.758142,56.803267,0.0 -133.892287,56.896605,0.0 -133.737849,56.892713,0.0 -134.019795,57.01438,0.0 -133.874778,57.085768,0.0 -133.327012,56.9966,0.0 -133.263967,56.921598,0.0 -133.295336,57.003543,0.0 -133.05339,56.977147,0.0</coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon><Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>-133.965053,56.081285,0.0 -134.037873,56.10517,0.0 -134.054234,56.312116,0.0 -134.100897,56.17433,0.0 -134.187286,56.176274,0.0 -134.098392,56.134053,0.0 -134.108387,55.998775,0.0 -134.222559,56.066278,0.0 -134.193969,56.155437,0.0 -134.26647,56.255722,0.0 -134.161738,56.307116,0.0 -134.282858,56.291003,0.0 -134.282583,56.355729,0.0 -134.181166,56.436285,0.0 -134.162004,56.366836,0.0 -134.109756,56.404894,0.0 -134.051179,56.359061,0.0 -134.030356,56.477961,0.0 -134.070058,56.554911,0.0 -134.136176,56.486575,0.0 -134.308129,56.559914,0.0 -134.087854,56.641589,0.0 -134.253133,56.612417,0.0 -134.219225,56.689366,0.0 -134.319238,56.657143,0.0 -134.395078,56.721027,0.0 -134.401489,56.852435,0.0 -134.275073,56.795206,0.0 -134.323113,56.893544,0.0 -134.108654,56.842713,0.0 -134.26537,56.936598,0.0 -133.995315,56.874098,0.0 -133.927566,56.801593,0.0 -133.924249,56.714652,0.0 -134.026461,56.646869,0.0 -133.863945,56.723259,0.0 -133.870589,56.807987,0.0 -133.719509,56.766324,0.0 -133.777599,56.684088,0.0 -133.693144,56.599361,0.0 -133.740358,56.56019,0.0 -133.92232,56.613806,0.0 -133.845365,56.571582,0.0 -133.91927,56.500746,0.0 -133.827332,56.435458,0.0 -133.911218,56.424904,0.0 -133.85564,56.278789,0.0 -133.975081,56.355729,0.0 -133.985914,56.268507,0.0 -133.889538,56.222946,0.0 -133.949533,56.199338,0.0 -133.965053,56.081285,0.0</coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon><Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>-132.803653,56.786041,0.0 -132.53255,56.577433,0.0 -132.751712,56.552429,0.0 -132.720308,56.511041,0.0 -132.774785,56.49437,0.0 -132.941723,56.509375,0.0 -132.958108,56.593804,0.0 -132.883371,56.636586,0.0 -132.965623,56.796038,0.0 -132.803653,56.786041,0.0</coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon><Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>-132.337805,56.479648,0.0 -132.162511,56.352711,0.0 -132.005321,56.336315,0.0 -131.92335,56.196861,0.0 -132.05781,56.111031,0.0 -132.303892,56.231852,0.0 -132.35141,56.277973,0.0 -132.337805,56.479648,0.0</coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon><Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>-132.704771,56.455756,0.0 -132.615863,56.396037,0.0 -132.678911,56.265194,0.0 -132.846705,56.231302,0.0 -133.058116,56.341866,0.0 -132.941995,56.447423,0.0 -132.704771,56.455756,0.0</coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon><Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>-132.47363,55.495631,0.0 -132.26169,55.442129,0.0 -132.470278,55.38436,0.0 -132.254761,55.409911,0.0 -132.155027,55.362969,0.0 -132.086939,55.262141,0.0 -132.241115,55.254357,0.0 -132.240834,55.192691,0.0 -132.089164,55.200748,0.0 -132.012234,55.272412,0.0 -131.970272,55.226027,0.0 -131.998899,55.100476,0.0 -132.096662,55.103254,0.0 -132.07444,55.038815,0.0 -132.220243,54.99215,0.0 -131.964713,55.025479,0.0 -132.012495,54.967703,0.0 -131.973584,54.894651,0.0 -132.053592,54.889647,0.0 -131.951107,54.787988,0.0 -132.008081,54.779374,0.0 -132.005588,54.690207,0.0 -132.290567,54.714374,0.0 -132.216373,54.793544,0.0 -132.354993,54.799096,0.0 -132.267215,54.839091,0.0 -132.389726,54.923821,0.0 -132.380539,55.016043,0.0 -132.46889,54.902144,0.0 -132.454455,54.984921,0.0 -132.532245,54.932423,0.0 -132.599167,54.96825,0.0 -132.533893,55.015756,0.0 -132.574448,55.036866,0.0 -132.460285,55.04326,0.0 -132.558334,55.12158,0.0 -132.616376,55.061028,0.0 -132.561386,55.165189,0.0 -132.643042,55.249923,0.0 -132.610819,55.167701,0.0 -132.668314,55.137695,0.0 -132.780004,55.182146,0.0 -132.805813,55.267699,0.0 -133.004455,55.202707,0.0 -132.902215,55.279366,0.0 -133.224169,55.282706,0.0 -133.262237,55.338543,0.0 -133.195558,55.384385,0.0 -132.849147,55.35131,0.0 -132.996925,55.375482,0.0 -133.066673,55.426877,0.0 -132.978863,55.447141,0.0 -133.129162,55.489098,0.0 -133.070291,55.573819,0.0 -132.910013,55.627679,0.0 -133.255344,55.573267,0.0 -133.354775,55.609642,0.0 -133.376152,55.722684,0.0 -133.237542,55.74658,0.0 -133.138127,55.886025,0.0 -133.243075,55.904077,0.0 -133.260082,56.152134,0.0 -133.618962,56.207131,0.0 -133.634502,56.276293,0.0 -133.567025,56.296582,0.0 -133.612287,56.347966,0.0 -133.325615,56.326029,0.0 -133.315358,56.268801,0.0 -133.190049,56.329924,0.0 -133.062264,56.241582,0.0 -133.025609,56.176302,0.0 -133.139777,56.11658,0.0 -133.079776,56.052131,0.0 -132.72725,55.989626,0.0 -132.494455,55.813789,0.0 -132.437501,55.622951,0.0 -132.381659,55.669075,0.0 -132.292515,55.536297,0.0 -132.145846,55.480185,0.0 -132.170839,55.446296,0.0 -132.541679,55.622674,0.0 -132.564165,55.567405,0.0 -132.511408,55.544349,0.0 -132.679719,55.452419,0.0 -132.47363,55.495631,0.0</coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon><Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>-132.391972,56.335756,0.0 -132.396699,56.221573,0.0 -132.480019,56.189628,0.0 -132.351103,56.216302,0.0 -132.108893,56.115478,0.0 -132.201657,56.085199,0.0 -132.129461,55.927986,0.0 -132.181674,55.965758,0.0 -132.340003,55.913519,0.0 -132.427257,55.955738,0.0 -132.38166,56.026023,0.0 -132.636704,56.048802,0.0 -132.697528,56.107412,0.0 -132.696154,56.221857,0.0 -132.605024,56.23102,0.0 -132.517528,56.338249,0.0 -132.391972,56.335756,0.0</coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon><Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>-133.287273,56.128519,0.0 -133.319218,55.993516,0.0 -133.478933,56.022388,0.0 -133.620044,55.919062,0.0 -133.791729,55.920726,0.0 -133.681448,56.066011,0.0 -133.486714,56.085736,0.0 -133.619502,56.130453,0.0 -133.287273,56.128519,0.0</coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon><Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>-131.606391,55.319646,0.0 -131.82529,55.454911,0.0 -131.645025,55.544915,0.0 -131.616399,55.597128,0.0 -131.705846,55.619351,0.0 -131.69364,55.676296,0.0 -131.514752,55.726018,0.0 -131.711128,55.731845,0.0 -131.482527,55.786854,0.0 -131.685587,55.832962,0.0 -131.43669,55.839908,0.0 -131.573925,55.906013,0.0 -131.233359,55.953515,0.0 -130.936975,55.641876,0.0 -130.968096,55.391043,0.0 -131.028369,55.405484,0.0 -131.049755,55.267158,0.0 -131.14448,55.196601,0.0 -131.308358,55.234651,0.0 -131.217511,55.305209,0.0 -131.227525,55.405756,0.0 -131.294749,55.273538,0.0 -131.460853,55.281034,0.0 -131.271714,55.437149,0.0 -131.350571,55.644642,0.0 -131.334456,55.419646,0.0 -131.463632,55.327703,0.0 -131.44502,55.528251,0.0 -131.521708,55.476028,0.0 -131.468332,55.355481,0.0 -131.523627,55.292707,0.0 -131.606391,55.319646,0.0</coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon><Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>-131.82114,55.41241,0.0 -131.618322,55.283261,0.0 -131.761689,55.247423,0.0 -131.726683,55.134374,0.0 -131.824461,55.211314,0.0 -131.866946,55.367969,0.0 -131.82114,55.41241,0.0</coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon><Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>-131.468907,55.23548,0.0 -131.375006,55.196595,0.0 -131.35666,55.035216,0.0 -131.476957,55.000494,0.0 -131.537505,55.090761,0.0 -131.521696,55.032711,0.0 -131.599728,54.994931,0.0 -131.594177,55.106316,0.0 -131.518646,55.128259,0.0 -131.585301,55.251592,0.0 -131.468907,55.23548,0.0</coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon><Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>-133.103853,55.245203,0.0 -132.957493,55.061865,0.0 -133.081358,55.085474,0.0 -132.756668,54.821874,0.0 -132.716661,54.764654,0.0 -132.758897,54.739371,0.0 -132.670272,54.66381,0.0 -132.841932,54.689088,0.0 -132.955277,54.791875,0.0 -132.906935,54.836309,0.0 -133.15027,54.943797,0.0 -133.215271,55.094636,0.0 -133.118282,55.101585,0.0 -133.215824,55.169637,0.0 -133.103853,55.245203,0.0</coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon></MultiGeometry>
</Placemark>
</Folder>
<Folder>
<name>Info</name>
<Snippet>
</Snippet>
<Style>
<BalloonStyle >
<text>$[description]</text>
</BalloonStyle>
</Style>
<description>
<![CDATA[Source File: US-States.shp<br>Legend: Single Symbol<br>Label: CODE<br>
<br>
<hr>ShapeFile to Google Earth<p>
<font color="blue">
</i>
</font>
</p>]]>
</description>
</Folder>
</Document>
</kml>
```

What i need to do now ?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78912/discussion-on-answer-by-dhamodaran-how-to-read-kml-data-in-c).

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution using XML Linq

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;



namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
            List<XElement> placemarks = doc.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "Placemark").ToList();

            var states = placemarks.Select(x => new {
                    state = x.Descendants().Where(y => y.Name.LocalName == "name").Select(z => z.Value).FirstOrDefault(),
                    descendants = x
                }).Select(xa => xa.descendants.Descendants().Where(x1 => x1.Name.LocalName == "MultiGeometry").Select(y => 
                new
                {
                  state = xa.state,
                  coordinates = xa.descendants.Descendants().Where(y1 => y1.Name.LocalName == "coordinates").Select(z => z.Value).ToList()
                })).Where(x => x.FirstOrDefault() != null);


            var akCoordinates = states.Where(x => x.FirstOrDefault().state == "AK").Select(y => y.FirstOrDefault().coordinates);
        }
    }

}
```